# Less space (glue) inserted when using ~

Tags: luatex, luaotfload

```
\input luaotfload.sty

\font\bsk=[BaskervilleMTPro-Regular]:script=latn;
\bsk


If the dimension $M$ were less than the number $N$ of data sites, then the columns of $A$ couldn’t span the whole of~$R^N$, so  there would be some sets of data values~$F$ for which  there is no interpolant in the space of functions~$S$; if instead~$M$ were greater than~$N$, \dots 


\bye
```

I'm loading in plain luatex a otf font installed on my system.  When I'm using the feature `script=latn` which has the effect of enabling ligatures, a strange problem appears:  If I remove the `~` character before `$R^N$`, and put a space instead, then the printed space between "of" and "R^N" is slightly increased.  What is going on?

(with tracing)

```
\input luaotfload.sty

\font\bsk=[BaskervilleMTPro-Regular]:script=latn;
\bsk

\tracingonline1
\tracingoutput1
\showboxdepth\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth\maxdimen

If the dimension $M$ were less than the number $N$ of data sites, then
the columns of $A$ couldn’t span the whole of~$R^N$, so there would be
some sets of data values~$F$ for which there is no interpolant in the
space of functions~$S$; if instead~$M$ were greater than~$N$, \dots


If the dimension $M$ were less than the number $N$ of data sites, then
the columns of $A$ couldn’t span the whole of $R^N$, so there would be
some sets of data values~$F$ for which there is no interpolant in the
space of functions~$S$; if instead~$M$ were greater than~$N$, \dots


\bye
```

[image]

Here is the log file

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020)  (format=luatex 2020.12.29)  4 JAN 2021 11:28
 restricted system commands enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.tex
File: ltluatex.tex 2020/09/25 v1.1s LuaTeX support for plain TeX (core) 
\e@alloc@attribute@count=\count277
\e@alloc@ccodetable@count=\count278
\e@alloc@luafunction@count=\count279
\e@alloc@whatsit@count=\count280
\e@alloc@bytecode@count=\count281
\e@alloc@luachunk@count=\count282
\catcodetable@initex=\catcodetable1
\catcodetable@string=\catcodetable2
\catcodetable@latex=\catcodetable3
\catcodetable@atletter=\catcodetable4
)
Lua module: luaotfload 2020-12-31 3.16 Lua based OpenType font support
Lua module: lualibs 2020-12-30 2.73 ConTeXt Lua standard libraries.
Lua module: lualibs-extended 2020-12-30 2.73 ConTeXt Lua libraries -- extended c
ollection.
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/matteo/.texlive2020/texmf-var
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
luaotfload | init : Loading fontloader "fontloader-2020-12-30.lua" from kpse-res
olved path "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/fontloader-
2020-12-30.lua".
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@noligature = 1
Lua-only attribute luaotfload@syllabe = 2
luaotfload | init : Context OpenType loader version 0x1.8e5604189374cp+1
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.node_processor' at position 1 in `hpack_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.glyph_stream' at position 1 in `glyph_stream_provider'.
Inserting `luaotfload.define_font' at position 1 in `define_font'.
Lua-only attribute luaotfload_color_attribute = 3
luaotfload | conf : Root cache directory is "/home/matteo/.texlive2020/texmf-var
/luatex-cache/generic/names".
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_sscale_dimens' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_
font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_font_index' at position 2 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.patch_cambria_domh' at position 3 in `luaotfload.patch
_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.fixup_fontdata' at position 1 in `luaotfload.patch_fon
t_unsafe'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_capheight' at position 4 in `luaotfload.patch_font
'.
Inserting `luaotfload.aux.set_xheight' at position 5 in `luaotfload.patch_font'.
Inserting `luaotfload.rewrite_fontname' at position 6 in `luaotfload.patch_font'
.)
luaotfload | db : Font names database loaded from /home/matteo/.texlive2020/texm
f-var/luatex-cache/generic/names/luaotfload-names.luc

Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(667.20255+0.0)x469.75499, direction TLT
.\vbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 14.0fil, direction TLT
..\glue -22.5
..\hbox(8.5+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 469.755fil, direction TLT
...\vbox(8.5+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 570.74255fill, direction TLT
..\glue(\topskip) 3.16669
..\hbox(6.83331+2.46)x469.75499, glue set 0.27213, direction TLT
...\localpar
....\localinterlinepenalty=0
....\localbrokenpenalty=0
....\localleftbox=null
....\localrightbox=null
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0, direction TLT
...\bsk I
...\bsk f
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.94 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk d
...\bsk i
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk m
...\bsk e
...\bsk n
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk s
...\bsk i
...\bsk o
...\bsk n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni M
...\kern1.09026 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk w
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk l
...\bsk e
...\bsk s
...\bsk s
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk a
...\bsk n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk n
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk u
...\bsk m
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk b
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni N
...\kern1.09026 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk o
...\bsk f
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.94 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk d
...\bsk a
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk t
...\bsk a
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk s
...\bsk i
...\bsk t
...\bsk e
...\bsk s
...\kern-0.19 (font)
...\bsk ,
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.5625 minus 0.66666
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\bsk n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk c
...\bsk o
...\bsk l
...\bsk u
...\bsk m
...\bsk n
...\bsk s
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk o
...\bsk f
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.94 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni A
...\mathoff
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk c
...\bsk o
...\bsk u
...\bsk l
...\bsk d
...\bsk n
...\kern-0.28 (font)
...\bsk ’
...\kern-0.19 (font)
...\bsk t
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk s
...\bsk p
...\bsk a
...\bsk n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk w
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk h
...\bsk o
...\bsk l
...\bsk e
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
..\penalty 150
..\glue(\baselineskip) 1.12773
..\hbox(8.41226+2.46)x469.75499, glue set 0.28775, direction TLT
...\bsk o
...\bsk f
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni R
...\kern0.07726 (italic)
...\hbox(4.78334+0.0)x7.58473, shifted -3.62892, direction TLT
....\seveni N
...\mathoff
...\bsk ,
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.5625 minus 0.66666
...\bsk s
...\bsk o
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk w
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk o
...\bsk u
...\bsk l
...\bsk d
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk b
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk s
...\bsk o
...\bsk m
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk s
...\bsk e
...\bsk t
...\bsk s
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk o
...\bsk f
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.94 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk d
...\bsk a
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk t
...\bsk a
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk v
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk a
...\bsk l
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk u
...\bsk e
...\bsk s
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni F
...\kern1.3889 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk f
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk o
...\bsk r
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk w
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk h
...\bsk i
...\bsk c
...\kern-0.11 (font)
...\bsk h
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk i
...\bsk s
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk n
...\bsk o
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk i
...\bsk n
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk t
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \kern-0.19 (font)
....< \bsk -
....= \kern0.27 (font)
...\bsk p
...\bsk o
...\bsk l
...\bsk a
...\bsk n
...\bsk t
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk i
...\bsk n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk s
...\bsk p
...\bsk a
...\bsk c
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk o
...\bsk f
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.94 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk f
...\bsk u
...\bsk n
...\bsk c
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk t
...\bsk i
...\bsk o
...\bsk n
...\bsk s
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni S
...\kern0.57637 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\bsk ;
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.875 minus 0.55554
...\bsk i
...\bsk f
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
..\penalty 150
..\glue(\baselineskip) 2.70668
..\hbox(6.83331+2.46)x469.75499, glue set 325.11514fil, direction TLT
...\bsk i
...\bsk n
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk s
...\bsk t
...\bsk e
...\bsk a
...\bsk d
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni M
...\kern1.09026 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk w
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk g
...\kern0.18 (font)
...\bsk r
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\bsk a
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk t
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk a
...\bsk n
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni N
...\kern1.09026 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\bsk ,
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.5625 minus 0.66666
...\mathon
...\hbox(1.05554+0.0)x11.66661, direction TLT
....\teni :
....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
....\teni :
....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
....\teni :
...\glue 1.66663
...\mathoff
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
..\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
..\glue(\baselineskip) 2.70668
..\hbox(6.83331+2.46)x469.75499, glue set 0.27213, direction TLT
...\localpar
....\localinterlinepenalty=0
....\localbrokenpenalty=0
....\localleftbox=null
....\localrightbox=null
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0, direction TLT
...\bsk I
...\bsk f
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.94 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk d
...\bsk i
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk m
...\bsk e
...\bsk n
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk s
...\bsk i
...\bsk o
...\bsk n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni M
...\kern1.09026 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk w
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk l
...\bsk e
...\bsk s
...\bsk s
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk a
...\bsk n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk n
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk u
...\bsk m
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk b
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni N
...\kern1.09026 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk o
...\bsk f
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.94 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk d
...\bsk a
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk t
...\bsk a
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk s
...\bsk i
...\bsk t
...\bsk e
...\bsk s
...\kern-0.19 (font)
...\bsk ,
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.5625 minus 0.66666
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\bsk n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk c
...\bsk o
...\bsk l
...\bsk u
...\bsk m
...\bsk n
...\bsk s
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk o
...\bsk f
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.94 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni A
...\mathoff
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk c
...\bsk o
...\bsk u
...\bsk l
...\bsk d
...\bsk n
...\kern-0.28 (font)
...\bsk ’
...\kern-0.19 (font)
...\bsk t
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk s
...\bsk p
...\bsk a
...\bsk n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk w
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk h
...\bsk o
...\bsk l
...\bsk e
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
..\penalty 150
..\glue(\baselineskip) 1.12773
..\hbox(8.41226+2.46)x469.75499, glue set 0.24121, direction TLT
...\bsk o
...\bsk f
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.94 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni R
...\kern0.07726 (italic)
...\hbox(4.78334+0.0)x7.58473, shifted -3.62892, direction TLT
....\seveni N
...\mathoff
...\bsk ,
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.5625 minus 0.66666
...\bsk s
...\bsk o
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk w
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk o
...\bsk u
...\bsk l
...\bsk d
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk b
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk s
...\bsk o
...\bsk m
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk s
...\bsk e
...\bsk t
...\bsk s
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk o
...\bsk f
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.94 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk d
...\bsk a
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk t
...\bsk a
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk v
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk a
...\bsk l
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk u
...\bsk e
...\bsk s
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni F
...\kern1.3889 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk f
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk o
...\bsk r
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk w
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk h
...\bsk i
...\bsk c
...\kern-0.11 (font)
...\bsk h
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk i
...\bsk s
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk n
...\bsk o
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk i
...\bsk n
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk t
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \kern-0.19 (font)
....< \bsk -
....= \kern0.27 (font)
...\bsk p
...\bsk o
...\bsk l
...\bsk a
...\bsk n
...\bsk t
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk i
...\bsk n
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk s
...\bsk p
...\bsk a
...\bsk c
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk o
...\bsk f
...\glue(\spaceskip) 3.94 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk f
...\bsk u
...\bsk n
...\bsk c
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk t
...\bsk i
...\bsk o
...\bsk n
...\bsk s
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni S
...\kern0.57637 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\bsk ;
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.875 minus 0.55554
...\bsk i
...\bsk f
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
..\penalty 150
..\glue(\baselineskip) 2.70668
..\hbox(6.83331+2.46)x469.75499, glue set 325.11514fil, direction TLT
...\bsk i
...\bsk n
...\discretionary (penalty 50)
....< \bsk -
...\bsk s
...\bsk t
...\bsk e
...\bsk a
...\bsk d
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni M
...\kern1.09026 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk w
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk g
...\kern0.18 (font)
...\bsk r
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk e
...\bsk a
...\kern-0.1 (font)
...\bsk t
...\bsk e
...\bsk r
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\bsk t
...\bsk h
...\bsk a
...\bsk n
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.25 minus 0.83333
...\mathon
...\teni N
...\kern1.09026 (italic)
...\mathoff
...\bsk ,
...\glue(\spaceskip) 2.5 plus 1.5625 minus 0.66666
...\mathon
...\hbox(1.05554+0.0)x11.66661, direction TLT
....\teni :
....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
....\teni :
....\glue(\thinmuskip) 1.66663
....\teni :
...\glue 1.66663
...\mathoff
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
.\glue(\baselineskip) 17.55556
.\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 232.37749fil, direction TLT
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
..\tenrm 1
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil

{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map})</home/ma
tteo/texmf/fonts/opentype/monotype/BaskervilleMTPro/BaskervilleMTPro-Regular.otf
></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb></us
r/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 28680 bytes).

PDF statistics: 27 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 17 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 131072)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 100000000)
```

As suggested by Marcel Krüger, the problem may be in the kerning inserted between the f and the space, which is disabled with the `\penalty10000` of `~`.  Here is the information about the kerning of the character "f" in this font.
[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this with a freely available font?

Comment: can you demonstrate this with a publicly available font or is it specific to this one? either way could you show the log with this tracing turned on (and two paragraphs with and without the `~`)  (too long, I'll add it to your question)

Comment: David, do you forget that LaTeX has \showoutput?

Comment: @DonaldArseneau The OP is using plain LuaTeX and plain does not have `\showoutput`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the edit.  I've added the missing information.

Comment: Regarding what is going on: The font adds kerning between the `f` and the space, but when using `~` the penalty before the glue is "hiding" it, suppressing the kerning in the process. This probably needs a fontloader change to skip the penalty here, but it's complicated. Please add an issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues).

Comment: @MarcelKrüger No, I can't with a freely available font, I have found no other font with this issue.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger  If I open the font in FontForge for instance, where can I find the kerning inserted between the f and the space, so that I can try to remove it and see if the problem was actually there as you guess?

Comment: @User Before changing the font, you could start with disabling the most suspicious features and see if this changes anything: Add `-kern;-dist;` after `script=latn;`

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Yes, adding `-kern` seems fine, but then the ligatures are disabled too.

Comment: @User `-spacekern` should disable only the space kerning, but this obviously doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Yes, indeed it does.  But I was wrong before, `-kern` doesn't disable ligatures.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marcel may fix this in luaotfload but a workaround could be...

[image]

I couldn't find a font with a kern with space so I took a copy of TeX Gyre Termes and added a pair for f-space with (excessive) value 1000 using fontforge, so the effect is obvious.

Surprisingly if you directly look at the space with `\lastskip` you see a normal word space, but this code extracts the previous character and makes a box to extract the modified glue node and add after adding a nobreak penalty.

```
\input luaotfload.sty

\font\bsk=[./texgyretermes-regular-fspace.otf]:script=latn;
\bsk


\tracingonline1
\tracingoutput1
\showboxdepth\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth\maxdimen




If the dimension $M$ were less than the number $N$ of data sites, then
the columns of $A$ couldn’t span the whole of~$R^N$, so there would be
some sets of data values~$F$ for which there is no interpolant in the
space of functions~$S$; if instead~$M$ were greater than~$N$, \dots

\protected\def~{\directlua{
local n=tex.nest[tex.nest.ptr].tail
if (n.id==29) % glyph
then
tex.sprint('\detokenize{\\setbox0\\hbox{\\char' .. n.char .. '\\spacefactor=1000{} }\\setbox0\\hbox{\\unhbox0 \\global\\skip1\\lastskip}\\nobreak\\hskip\\skip1\\relax}')
else
tex.sprint('\detokenize{\\leavevmode\\nobreak\\ }')
end
}}

If the dimension $M$ were less than the number $N$ of data sites, then
the columns of $A$ couldn’t span the whole of~$R^N$, so there would be
some sets of data values~$F$ for which there is no interpolant in the
space of functions~$S$; if instead~$M$ were greater than~$N$, \dots


If the dimension $M$ were less than the number $N$ of data sites, then
the columns of $A$ couldn’t span the whole of $R^N$, so there would be
some sets of data values~$F$ for which there is no interpolant in the
space of functions~$S$; if instead~$M$ were greater than~$N$, \dots



\bye
```

Comment: It seems to work fine!  Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: The `~` defined in this way behaves differently from the standard one in a particular situation.  When we have nonfrenchspacings, so that after a dot a bigger space is inserted, your `~` doesn't suppress the bigger space.  For instance, if I write `fig.~5` to refer to a figure, between `fig.` and `5` there is a big space, as if the dot after `fig` is the end of a sentence.  Can you see why this happens?

Comment: @User oh zzzz  I can't look now but previously the nobreak  penalty node hid the previous character so the`.` didn't force the end of sentence space, this code makes the previous character visible so you get the character-space kern but now you also get the spacefactor, I guess you can add `\\@`  so `{}\\@ ` not `{} ` to locally reset the spacefactor

Comment: I tried adding replacing `{}` with `{}\\@`, but luatex says that `\@` is undefined.  I probably understood wrongly your correction.  Where should I add `\\@`?

Comment: @User sorry forgot this was plain tex use `\\spacefactor=1000{} ` instead of `{} `  (latex has `\def\@{\spacefactor\@m{}}`)

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you :)

Comment: @User thanks for confirming, I updated code in answer